# Is it possible to put a toolbar button on the right side of it using wxpython?

Tags: python, button, wxpython, toolbar, position

I'm making a toolbar using wxpython and I want to put the Quit button on the right side of it, I don't want to put them sequencially.

Is it possible to define this position?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the quit button last, it will be on the right side.

Comment: more and less, if I only have two buttons, it will be the rightest one but still very near the left side right?

Comment: Correct. I don't know of a way to add a spacer between the buttons. Maybe you should create two toolbars and put them in a horizontal box sizer?